# Approved certificate Authority for Twilio

Tags: https, twilio, ca

I am trying to connect to a secure webservice from Twilio.  Twilio's documentation states they only approve connecting to secure sites issued by CA's approved by Mozilla. The link (https://mozillacaprogram.secure.force.com/CA/IncludedCACertificateReport) of the approved CA's listed in in Twilio is broken.

But after a little bit of googling it appears Mozilla recognizes "The Internet Security Research Group (ISRG)" as a valid CA.

My certificate is signed by "*Let's Encrypt Authority*" formally known as "*The Internet Security Research Group (ISRG)*"

I have never had a browser issue using this authority and all the on-line certificate validation sites I have tested indicate there is no problem with my certificate.

The Twilio error I am receiving is

```
Error - 11237 Certificate Invalid - Could not find path to certificate
```

My guess is Twilio does not recognize this CA as a legit signing authority which is unfortunate because they have over 36 Million certificates active.

Anybody using this authority?
Any suggestions on a proxy?
Could this be an issue on Twilio's side?

Comment: (1) Google "mozilla ca list" first hit leads to https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA/Included_Certificates (2) Although ISRG Root X1 has been published and is now on the Mozilla list (but not in my slightly older FF38esr) Letsencrypt is still encouraging/instructing people to use the cross-chain to the older and widely trusted IdenTrust DST Root CA X3. Check exactly what's in the intermediate provided by your server, especially since browsers are often cleverer at 'fixing' an offered chain than other client software.

Comment: Hey, I work at Twilio and would love to get that URL fixed in our documentation. Could you point me to the page you found that on?

Answer (score 0):

Do you by any chance use the "cert.pem" file as your certificate? If so, use "fullchain.pem" instead.

Let's Encrypt's certbot generates 4 files, https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#where-certs.
Of those, cert.pem contains only your server certificate, but not the full chain up to the root CA. And according to Twilio's docs, https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/11237, you need the certificate file with the full chain, which would be fullchain.pem